# How do insert a .csv file with an additional column with a default value of 0 while using BULK INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a set of records I am bulk inserting into a table with 5 columns and an additional column. I am wanting to set AdmissionUsed to a default value of 0 but still be able to insert the required records from the .csv file.

How would I be able to accomplish this??

```
BULK INSERT PatientAdmissions
FROM 'xyz.csv'
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO

CREATE TABLE PatientAdmissions
(NationalHealthIndex    INT NOT NULL, 
Gender VARCHAR (1) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT CHK_gender_check CHECK(Gender= 'M' Or Gender = 'F' ), 
AdmissionDate DATE NOT NULL, 
AdmissionType VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
TreatmentType VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
AdmissionUsed Int Null DEFAULT(0),
);
```

Comment: Sorry Gordon, I am actually using just a sql database.

Comment: It should work as it is, Have you actually tried this?

Comment: @M.Ali Yeah I have but am returning with the error 'Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 6 (AdmissionUsed).'